# Using appium can I get an apk from app center test as opposed to having the dev post a APK in a specific folder for me

Tags: azure-devops, appium

Here is my code below. I need the app path for the setup. I looked in Appium docs, app center test docs and through the forums nothing yet.

```
[SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var appPath = @"";

            //Platform, Device, Application
            var driverOption = new AppiumOptions();
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android"); ;
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Pixel 3 API 29 V10");
            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, appPath);
            _driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), driverOption);

            driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("ChromedriverExecutable", @"C:\driver\Chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: You have to add a variable in the app centre that gives you the path of the latest build. And then use that variable in a batch script on the app centre.

Comment: Does that mean the app path will change every iteration and I will not know what it changes to or is this a one time and then I get the app path? Do I have to have an acount to access the apk in the app path?

Comment: After every build app center creates the build on a specific location. Your variable will store that path.